# Calculation of Math.NET iterative solvers are being canceled unexpectedly

Tags: vb.net, mathnet-numerics

I am comparing speed of my iterative solver in VB.NET and iterative solvers in Math.NET.
When I am using preconditioner with Math.NET iterative solvers, everything is good and it converged at about 0.1~0.2(s) but without preconditioner calculation was canceled at about 0.03(s). Status is Canceled (by user). Since I didn't cancel the calculation and I even don't know how I could cancel calulation by myself. I don't know source of problem.
I have my own iterative solvers and sometime when convergence is not fast and it takes more than 2 minutes, visual studio became paused by itself, I don't know why?!
I think visual studio canceled the calculation. Do you know how to solve this weird problem?
By the way, I am using VS2015.1 and Math.NET 3.4, and I am using VB over 10 years.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find it out. It was because of .NET "ContextSwitchDeadlock", and by disabling it in exception dialog (Ctrl+Alt+e), it completely resolved.